# How to call specific method based on user selection in DropDownList in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView` illustrated in the screen shots below: I need to call a specific `Method` based on the item selected by the user. I tried several approach, included using `SelectedValue` and `OnDataBind` events not getting it right. I am having trouble getting access to the `DropDownList` and having it's event call the `Methods`.

*Default view:*

[image]

*Selection changed:*

[image]

*Code:*

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdLoadData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">

<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Example">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExampleDropDownList"  runat="server" 
     AutoPostBack="true" Width="100">
    <asp:ListItem Text="---- Select --" Value="select" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Do Task A" Value="Task A" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Do Task B" Value="Task B" />
</asp:DropDownList> 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_NAME" HeaderText="Last Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FIRST_NAME" HeaderText="First Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="MiDDLE_NAME" HeaderText="Middle Name" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer ID">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblCustomerID" Text='<%#Eval("CUST_ID") %>' runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

*Code Behind:*

```
public partial class example : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private DbConnection GetDatabaseConnection(string name)
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings settings =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name];
        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory
        (settings.ProviderName);
        DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = settings.ConnectionString;
        return conn;
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection =  
            (SqlConnection)(GetDatabaseConnection("EDMS")))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new 
                    SqlCommand("ExampleStoredProcedure", connection);

                grdLoadData.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                grdLoadData.DataBind();
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    } 

    //Call if task A selected in DDL
    public void DoTaskA()
    {
        // do things here
    }

   //Call if task B selected in DDL
    public void DoTaskB()
    {
        // do things here
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: You can raise RowCommand by adding button next to DropDownList, this article will show you how to do that, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21163/Trick-Tip-Raise-a-GridView-RowCommand-event-from-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.Parent.Parent;
            int idx = row.RowIndex;
            if (ddl.SelectedValue == "Task A")
            {
                DoTaskA();
            }
            else if (ddl.SelectedValue == "Task B")
            {

                DoTaskB();
            }


        }
        public void DoTaskA()
        {
            // do things here
        }

        //Call if task B selected in DDL
        public void DoTaskB()
        {
            // do things here
        }
```

- And yea, Don't forget to include that in your design

  ```
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExampleDropDownList"  runat="server" 
              AutoPostBack="true" Width="100" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
             <asp:ListItem Text="---- Select --" Value="select" />
             <asp:ListItem Text="Do Task A" Value="Task A" />
             <asp:ListItem Text="Do Task B" Value="Task B" />
         </asp:DropDownList>
  ```